# Any idea how to open bytes object in new tab?

Tags: python, https, byte

I am requesting an api to grant access to communicate with application for integration. While requesting I am getting response which is in *bytes object* that is why i am unable to open it in new tab because I want login to access my application.

```
header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    response = requests.get(
        'https://api.getbase.com/oauth2/authorize',
        data='client_id=' + self.client_id + '&response_type=code&redirect_uri='
             + self.redirect_uri, headers=header).content

webbrowser.open_new_tab(response)
```

Comment: I'm confused. How is your code opening anything in a new tab? `requests` doesn't interact with web browsers in any way, AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, so you're using `webbrowser`. Makes sense. But `open_new_tab` requires a URL. Is `requests.get(...).content` a URL? In my experience the data returned by `requests.get` usually does not return a URL, but maybe this particular request does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just fixing your stated problem, you need to `decode` the bytes into a string or just use the `text` attribute.

that said, your code seems unnecessarily fragile and might be nicer as:

```
response = requests.post('https://api.getbase.com/oauth2/authorize', data={
  'client_id': self.client_id,
  'response_type': 'code',
  'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri
})
# make sure we throw an exception on failure
response.raise_for_status()

webbrowser.open_new_tab(response.text)
```

that way you can let `requests` deal with encoding/escaping the parameters appropriately.  the default encoding/data type with an HTTP POST request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as you need.  GET requests don't send a body, so I'm not sure how your previous code was working